# SMTP Transporter through AWS WorkMail

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses, nodemailer, amazon-workmail

I've created an AWS Workmail account, and I'd like to send an email from a server (NodeJS) using Nodemailer.

Please correct me if any of my understandings are wrong, but email services are just servers using the SMTP protocol. When I send an email, the server lookup to determine where to send the mail to is done through MX records.

My 2 questions are:

Can I redirect a Domain's MX records to a public inbox? For example "user@mydomain.com" will forward all it's mail to "user@gmail.com"?

Can I use Workmail as a transporter in nodemailer? For example:

`transport: 'smtps://user@mydomain.com:pass@smtp.awsworkmail.com',`

Any helpful resources are very welcome. Thank you in advance!